# Derived method being called instead of Base

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm forgetting why a base class method would call a derived virtual method when the method is not prefaced with `this->` or `Derived::` of an object of type `Derived*` See the commented line in Arc::SetAngles(...):

Abstract:

```
class Shape {
    public:
    //...
    protected:
    //...
    virtual void CalculateArea()=0;
    virtual void CalculateCenter()=0;
    private:
    //...
};
```

Base:

```
void Arc::CalculateArea() {
    _area = 0.5 * _radius * _radius * _theta;
}

void Arc::CalculateCenter() {
    double e = GetEndAngle();
    double s = GetStartAngle();
    double d = e - s;

    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;
    double offset = 0.0;
    if(d < 0.0) {
        offset = a2de::A2DE_PI;
    }
    x = (GetPosition().GetX() + std::cos(((s + e) / 2.0) + offset) * _radius);
    y = (GetPosition().GetY() + -std::sin(((s + e) / 2.0) + offset) * _radius);
    _center = Vector2D(x, y);
    return;
}
void Arc::SetAngles(double startAngle, double endAngle) {
    if(startAngle < 0.0) {
        startAngle += A2DE_2PI;
    }
    if(endAngle < 0.0) {
        endAngle += A2DE_2PI;
    }
    _startAngle = std::fmod(startAngle, A2DE_2PI);
    _endAngle = std::fmod(endAngle, A2DE_2PI);

    //must call base version explicitly otherwise Sector:: versions are called when object is of type Sector* regardless if prefaced with this-> or nothing.

    Arc::CalculateCenter();
    Arc::CalculateLength();
    Arc::CalculateArea();
}
```

Derived:

```
void Sector::CalculateArea() {
    _area = (_radius * _radius * _theta) / 2.0;
}

void Sector::CalculateCenter() {
    double x = (4 * _radius) / (3 * a2de::A2DE_PI);
    x += this->GetX();
    _center = Vector2D(x, GetY());
}
void Sector::SetAngles(double startAngle, double endAngle) {
    Arc::SetAngles(startAngle, endAngle);
    Sector::CalculateArea();
    Sector::CalculateCenter();
}
```

Comment: Because the rules of the language say it should be so.

Comment: You've got a lot of code here that's not relevant to the question, this could be more concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ was designed to give you this choice:

1. Use non-virtual function - base-class invocation uses base-class method.
2. Use virtual function - base-class invocation uses derived-class method.

Your choice, which behavior do you want?

THAT said, there's some confusion in your code & inheritance hierarchy.

IF a Sector IS-A Arc, then arguably (geometric argument here, not OO design argument) the calculation of Sector area and Arc area should be the same.  And looking at your code, they are - you might drop the `Sector::CalculateArea` (diff code for same formula).

HOWEVER, the requirement that the `CalculateCenter` method be different for the two types, and that the base-class code cannot leverage the derived class override (geometric argument AND OO argument), STRONGLY suggests that a Sector IS NOT an Arc.

You're code may be inheriting for the sake of inheriting, and in this case poorly.  Ask yourself if the proper inheritance might be both from `Shape`.

Going back to a strictly Geometric argument, an Arc IS NOT a Sector: An arc is on the perimeter of a circle (curved line, if you will), and a sector is a portion of the circle (pie shaped).  This is seen in your code by completely disparate implementations.

Comment: The inheritance was an attempt to leverage code reuse. Now, looking at it, a `Sector` CONTAINS an `Arc` at its perimeter. I can still reuse the same code and just delegate to the contained `Arc` when needed. Thanks.